# How to export two default modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to export withTranslation and GoogleApiWrapper.

So I wrote the following at the end of my Details.js file:

```
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'MY TOKEN'
})(Details);
export const SecondComponent = withTranslation()(Details);
```

Turns out this doesn't work, because when I load my page, it shows me errors like 't is not a function' and such.

Previously I only had:

```
   export default withTranslation()(Details);
```

And that worked fine but now I'm trying to add a map using the google API.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to mixed export default and export const instead:

```
export const GoogleApiWrapper({apiKey: 'MY TOKEN'})(Details);
export const SecondComponent = withTranslation()(Details);
```

So you can import them like this:

```
import { GoogleApiWrapper, SecondComponent } from './dir/to/details';
```

Comment: there seems to be a syntax error on the first line, are you sure I can export like that?

Comment: can you show us the whole content of Details.js file? and how you import it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you CAN'T.

The word **default** itself simply means, in any given context, you expect a single source of returned value. You don't even need any names, because you can name it whatever you want.

So, in conclusion, you can't have two default exports. The same when asking yourself which one you'd choose when you import a default from a library or package, you always want it as clear as possible.

Here's a short cheatsheet you can have a look at:

```
// Name Export | Name Import
export const name = 'value'
import { name } from '...'


// Default Export | Default Import
export default 'value'
import anyName from '...'


// Rename Export | NameImport
export { name as newName }
import { newName } from '...'


// Name + Default | Import All
export const name = 'value'
export default 'defaultValue'
import * as anyName from '...' 

=> access by: anyName.name, anyName.default

// Name + Default | Import Mixing 
export const name = 'value'
export default 'defaultValue'
import default, { name } from '...' 

// Export List + Rename | Import List + Rename
export {
  name1,
  name2 as newName2
}
import {
  name1 as newName1,
  newName2
} from '...'
==> This is the devil dev, jk
```

Like with anything, there is no right or wrong answer. The right way is always what’s best for you and your team.

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

You can only default export one module per file. Either create another file or use named exports.